# ui-effects-wrapper covering element

Tags: jquery-ui

I had a problem with the ui-effects-wrapper covering other elements at seemingly random spots, thus creating dead zones particularly for anchors.  Problem was solved simply by adding a z-index:-1; to the css for .ui-effects-wrapper.